# NSDate returning NULL when debugging in phone

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdateformatter

This NSDate able to get the show when i debugging in simulator from xcode. But when I debugging in iphone6 it show NULL.

```
NSString *dateWithTime = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"2019/03/18 09:30 AM"];

    NSDateFormatter *fmt = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    fmt.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm a";
    [fmt setAMSymbol:@"am"];
    [fmt setPMSymbol:@"pm"];

    fmt.timeZone = [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone];
    NSDate *localDate = [fmt dateFromString:dateWithTime];
    NSLog(@"DATE -- %@ ", [fmt stringFromDate:localDate]);
```

No idea is it because the phone timezone not using am/pm or any other causes.

Kindly please help me answer it.

Comment: What is the exact value of `dateWithTime`? Please put that in your question.

Comment: already edit the question. the date i stated in the dateWithTime.

Comment: Start by changing the `-` to `/` to match the string. Try changing `am` to `AM` to match the string. If none of those work, set the formatter's locale to the special locale of `en_US_POSIX` (which you should do either way).

Comment: thanks you so much. By setting thing locale does work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting the locale for the date formatter

```
fmt.locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"];
```

**Update**

For en_US_POSIX locale you can use:

```
 fmt.locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];
```

Comment: You don't want `en_US`, you want `en_US_POSIX`.